# Unexpected output from test program with pointers and levels of indirection in C

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{ 
   int z; int **x; int *y;
   x = (int **) malloc(sizeof(int*));
   *x = malloc(sizeof(int));
   **x = 5;
   y = *x; //POINT 1
   z = 3;
   *x = &z;//POINT 2
   printf("%d\n",*y);
   printf("%d\n", **x);
   **x = 2;
   printf("%d\n",*y);
   *y=1;
   printf("%d\n",z);
}
```

Output I get is as follows

5 // why is this 5?

3

5

2

My question is shouldn't the first output  print 3? Why is 5 being printed?

My question is does this program produce dangling reference or garbage? I am thinking that might be one of the reasons for this unexpected output. Can someone please explain.

Comment: No, your program merely leaks memory, but it doesn't write to unallocated memory nor does it result in dangling pointers.

Comment: Also, I don't see why the first should print `3`. You need to **think** about what a pointer is. Pointers are stored in memory themselves. They can be copied and passed around just like the objects they are pointing to (`int`s in this case). Furthermore, you need to understand that a pointer **is not a reference.**

Comment: y references to a pointer(*x) whose value is 5. You are dereferencing y, and getting 5. Thus the output is correct

Comment: @DimitrisFousteris Is this a case of dangling reference or garbage? or both?

Comment: this line:  *x = &z;//POINT 2 overlays the pointer to malloc'd memory.  This results in a memory leak.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets draw it out.

After you initialize `x`, `*x` and `**x` you memory looks something like this:

```
+---+     +----+     +---+
| x | --> | *x | --> | 5 |
+---+     +----+     +---+
```

The you assign `y`:

```
+---+     +----+
| x | --> | *x | --\
+---+     +----+    \     +---+
                     >--> | 5 |
           +---+    /     +---+
           | y | --/
           +---+
```

And then you make `*x` points somewhere else, so you have this:

```
+---+     +----+     +---+
| x | --> | *x | --> | z |
+---+     +----+     +---+

+---+     +---+
| y | --> | 5 |
+---+     +---+
```

In other words, you make `y` point to where `*x` is pointing, not to `*x` itself, so when you change where `*x` is pointing you don't change where `y` is pointing.

Comment: Drawing the pointers is just about the nicest thing to understand them. +1

Comment: Does my program produce dangling reference or garbage value?

Comment: @user2733436 No, there's no dangling pointers or garbage values.

Comment: @user2733436 No it does not. You just did not understand where your pointers are pointing.

Answer (score 1):

`x` points to a pointer(say `p`) that points to memory location. You stored the value `5` in that location.
`y` points to the location where the pointer `p` is pointing, a location with value `5`.
`z` is a memory location with value `3`.
Now `p` is made to point to the memory location of `z`. But this **DOES NOT** change where `y` is pointing. Hence it still points to a location with value `5`.

Answer (score 1):

In your program you have `y = *x;` which puts the pointer pointed to by x into the pointer variable y.  That area of memory pointed to by the pointer in x has a value of 5 since y now has that pointer, then *y is now 5.  You then put a new pointer into the pointer area that is pointed to by x.

```
int main()
{ 
   int z; int **x; int *y;
   x = (int **) malloc(sizeof(int*));  // create a pointer to a pointer variable
   *x = malloc(sizeof(int));          // create a pointer to an int that is put into the pointer that is pointed to by x ( x  ->  int pointer  ->  int )
   **x = 5;                           // set the int value pointed to by the pointer that is pointed to by x to 5
   y = *x; //POINT 1                 // assign the pointer to the int value to another pointer variable
   z = 3;
   *x = &z;//POINT 2                 // assign a new address to the pointer that is pointed to by x.
   printf("%d\n",*y);                // print the value pointed to by y which is 5
   printf("%d\n", **x);              // print the value that is pointed to by the pointer which is pointed to by x  which is 3
   **x = 2;
   printf("%d\n",*y);
   *y=1;
   printf("%d\n",z);
}
```